# How to return a value from a function in C?

Tags: c

```
int preced(char arr)
{
if(arr=='/')
    return 4;
if(arr=='*')
    return 3;
if(arr=='+' || arr=='-')
    return 2;
if(arr=='(')
    return 1;
}
```

The code written above gives me a warning : Function should return a value. 
I am unable to use the value that should have been returned by this function.
How do I fix this problem?

Comment: What if `arr` contains `?`, for example? *You* may be certain the function never is called with another value than those checked for, but the compiler is not so sure about that.

Answer (score 2):

Your function should *always* return a value. It doesn't because you only return when certain conditions are met, namely when `arr` is one of `'/'`, `'*'`, `'+'`, or `'('`.

You must make sure to cover all cases:

```
int preced(char arr)
{
  /* as above */

  return 42; // or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A return statement is not available inorder to return if all the `if` conditions fails.

just add

`return 0` at the end before exiting the function.

Answer (score 0):

You function is returning a value in condition. Always keep in mind that code inside `if` condition may or may not get executed every-time. In your case, `if` is returning a value based on a condition being `true`. What if those condition are not met at all. So, every function returning a value should always return one in every case i.e. the returned value should be **definite**

You can actually make use of `switch-case`

```
int preced (char arr)
switch(arr)
{
    case '/':
          return 4;
    case '*':
          return 3;
    case '+':
    case '-':
          return 2;
    case '(':
          return 1;
    default:
          return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how your code should be

```
int preced(char arr)
{
if(arr=='/')
    return 4;
else if(arr=='*')
    return 3;
else if(arr=='+' || arr=='-')
    return 2;
else if(arr=='(')
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
}
```

You got that warning because if `arr` is not any of the characters in your if statement, then the function will not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great place to use a switch, for readability mainly. Functionality remains the same:

```
int preced(char arr) {
    switch(arr) {
        case '/': return 4;
        case '*': return 3;;
        case '+': //will fallthrough
        case '-': return 2;
        case '(': return 1;
        default: return 0;
    }
}
```

The problem with your code was that there were ways the function could finish without returning something. In case all the if's where ignored because arr was for example 'a'. Maybe in your program this doesnt occur but the compiler wont know that and will give an error. In the switch above the 'default' case handles this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is warning about the fact that `preced` may return without a proper result, consider using a `switch` with a `default` case:

```
switch (arr) {
    case '/':
        return 4;
    case '*':
        return 3;
    case '+':
    case '-':
        return 2;
    case '(':
        return 1;
    default:
        return 0;
}
```

Also, note that `arr` doesn't seems a good name for a parameter expecting a `char`.